# Parsing Hexadecimal file looking for patterns

Tags: python, parsing, unicode, hex

I am working on parsing a unicode/hexadecimal file which essentially contains a series of "entries" that I am interested in. Right before these entries will be the following pattern:

```
0x 00 00 00 <LENGTH> 00 00
```

Where < LENGTH > is the length, in bytes, of the entry that follows. So, for example, an entry with this preceding it:

```
0x 00 00 00 48 00 00 ..........
```

The next 72 bytes (0x48 converted to decimal) will be the unicode entry that I care about.

Simply put, I can't figure out the best way to parse a file that's structured like this. Normal text files I would just use .split() to split each entry at a certain pattern, but in this case as each < LENGTH > will be different, I don't know if thats the best way to go about it.

I was thinking of using a function that takes the hex input (entire file), a start location, and end location to fetch each entry after walking through and getting the offsets for each entry, though i feel like there might be a more efficient way to do this.

Figured I would get some input before I started hacking away at it. Any thoughts?

EDIT: Some more information on the file structure. It is big-endian and the pattern that I am looking for is actually this, though for some reason only the FIRST entry does not follow this pattern (special case, I can deal with it later on):

```
0x 00 00 00 48 00 00 .........
```

Where 0x 48 is this size of the following entry. So there is two bytes of padding, then two bytes for the size, then two bytes of padding, then the entry. As I said, the first entry does not have the same padding for some reason, but I can deal with that later. Every other entry has the same padding before/after the size.

Comment: Hm. `00 00 00 ....` does not look like it's Unicode. You need to know how many *bytes* represent each single Unicode character (typically 2, but may be up to 4) and in what endianness they appear.

Comment: You were right. I edited with some more information. It is big endian and the padding before/after the size is better described above. Thanks!

Comment: it is not clear what is the actual content in the file. Update your question and include what is `print(repr(open('your_file', 'rb').read(2+2+0x48)))`?

Answer (score 0):

this may be a start (if you were to open a real file; uncomment the line `with open...`; the mode `rb` is vital there; you want to open the file in binary mode)

```
import io

# with open('filename.data', 'rb') as fle:
fle = io.StringIO('\x00\x00\x00\x48\x00\x01\x02')

# read the first 3 0x00
for _ in range(3):
    fle.read(1)
# read the length
length = ord(fle.read(1))
print(length)
data = fle.read(length)
```

Comment: The OP did not mention "binary" anywhere. That also shows in his example line - `0x` does not appear in a binary file.

Comment: oh, i thought that was short-hand for... well... binary chars in a file. but maybe i'm mistaken.